# Citing publications with stylized titles

Tags: titles, italics, citation

In a situation where the title of a work is stylized, e.g. "Choose the Red Pill *and* the Blue Pill", should this title be fully italicized as *Choose the Red Pill and the Blue Pill* when cited?

It would obviously leave out the emphasis from the title. Are there conventions on how to tackle these situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you italicize the title, then the entire title must be italicized. It doesn't matter that the word "and" is in italics on the actual book. Libraries and book stores don't recognize that little stylization as meaningful when they index or alphabetize books. There are a plethora of style manuals available both online and in book stores. Check with the folks you're delivering the paper to: a publisher, a university, your English teacher, your sociology teacher, or whoever else might be the audience for this paper. One of those folks or institutions may tell you which style manual to use.

Answer (score 5):

Bill's right that libraries and (most) bookshops don't worry about stylization within titles; and that the 'house style' for the place your writing is published is the most important factor. But if you *do* want to retain the emphasis on one word, the usual convention is to take out of italics the part that would normally be italicized: '*Choose the Red Pill* and *the Blue Pill*'.